# C# Checking if a query returns empty set not working?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been working on trying to check if a record exists in a database table. I have the following code and it is not working.

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("My connection string");
        string check = string.Format("Select COUNT(*) FROM User_Class WHERE user_class_name = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
        string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO User_Class (user_class_name) VALUE ('{0}');", TextBox1.Text);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(check, connection);
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //MySqlDataReader reader;
        connection.Open();
        if (cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery().Equals(0))//record does not exist
        {
            cmd2.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = "User Class Created!";
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "User Class Already Exists";
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

This code always goes to the else case. I have also tried doing this using `MySqlDataReader` but that is also not working. Why is it not returning 0 (or false/null)? What is the best way to check for an empty return?

Comment: check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se%28v=vs.110%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx This a method to show the async data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two issues here.

Firstly, you're calling `BeginExecuteNonQuery` - that doesn't return an integer, it returns an `IAsyncResult`. I strongly suspect that you don't want to be dealing with the asynchronous API at all.

Secondly, using `ExecuteNonQuery` isn't appropriate for a query anyway. I suspect you *actually* want `ExecuteScalar`:

```
if ((int) cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
```

You may need to cast to `long` instead of `int`; I don't know offhand what type of value it will return. However, that's a far more sensible call for a "SELECT COUNT" query.

I'd *then* suggest you use `ExecuteNonQuery` for the INSERT... after changing your code to use parameterized SQL instead of the [SQL-injection-inviting](http://bobby-tables.com) approach you're using now.

Comment: Note: `ExecuteScalar` may return `null` or `DBNull`; in that case casting to `int` will fail

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Will it return either of those for a SELECT COUNT query? (It can return plenty of types of value, but I'd expect it to return an integer for a SELECT COUNT...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for the very informative answer! I understand my mistake and have fixed it!

Comment: @JonSkeet I have not yet gotten to sanitizing the inputs this is simply for testing :)

Comment: @Andy: with parameterized SQL you don't have to sanitize the inputs. Get into the habit of *always* using parameterized SQL, however early you are in the process. Personally I think it ends up as simpler code anyway...

Comment: I feel like half the SO users who are told to use Parameterized SQL are asking why their code fails to handle either weird strings (e.g., containing quotes) or dates.  Parameterized SQL makes things easier for mere mortals, not just for Jon.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points - you are not calling the `BeginExecuteNonQuery()` command properly - I don't think you meant to all the Asynchronous method.

Also, you are calling the check with `ExecuteNonQuery` - that will just execute the query and return a result status - which unless the SQL fails will always be success, You should be using:

```
if ((long)(cmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0) == 0)
```

That will give you the results of the `Count(*)`

Finally - writing your embedded SQL like that leaves you open to hack - Look at this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I look forward to reading that article